# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS also 20.10 font characters not in ascending order 25471 < 5588350

Tags: boot, intel, amd-ryzen

First I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a new Ryzen system(4650g with b550 chipset board)

Installation is complete, but the first boot fails with an error message.

font characters not in ascending order 25471 < 5588350

stuck system and failed to boot.

I want to know about 'font characters not in ascending order 25471 < 5588350'